# Python ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

```
import enchant
message_decrypt= input("Enter the message you want to decrypt: ")
key= 0
def caesar_hack(message_decrypt,key):
    final_message=""
    d= enchant.Dict("en.US")
    f= d.check(message_decrypt)
    while f== False:
        for characters in message_decrypt:
            if ord(characters)<=90:
                if ord(characters)-key<ord("A"):
                    final_message= final_message+ chr(ord(characters)-key)
                else:
                    final_message= final_message+ chr(ord(characters)-key+26)
            else:
                if ord(characters)-key<ord("a"):
                    final_message=final_message+chr(ord(characters)-key)
                else:
                    final_message= final_message+chr(ord(characters)-key+26)
        key=key+1
        f= d.check(message_decrypt)
    else:
        print(final_message)
caesar_hack(message_decrypt, key)
```

Why doesn't this code work?
I'm trying to do a caesar cipher hack using the brute force technique. I get an error as below
[image: Error]

Can someone please help fix this code.

Comment: `ord(characters)-key` can go below 0, if your key was incremented many times. And `chr` take only `0-1,114,111` ranged values.

Comment: Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of tweaks I had to make to get your code to work, here's a working version:

```
import enchant
message_decrypt= input("Enter the message you want to decrypt: ")
key= 0
def caesar_hack(message_decrypt,key):
    final_message=""
    d= enchant.Dict("en.US")
    f= d.check(message_decrypt)
    while f== False:
        for characters in message_decrypt:
            if ord(characters)<=90:
                if ord(characters)-key<ord("A"):
                    final_message= final_message+ chr(ord(characters)-key+26)  # The additional 26 should be here, not below
                else:
                    final_message= final_message+ chr(ord(characters)-key)
            else:
                if ord(characters)-key<ord("a"):
                    final_message=final_message+chr(ord(characters)-key+26)  # The additional 26 should be here, not below
                else:
                    final_message= final_message+chr(ord(characters)-key)
        key=key+1
        f= d.check(final_message)  # Check should be on final_message, not message_decrypt
        if not f:
            final_message = ""  # Need to reset the final_message if not matched
    else:
        print(final_message)
caesar_hack(message_decrypt, key)
```

I've commented the main changes I made. One key one was checking `final_message` in the loop, not `message_decrypt` (and resetting it again for the next loop if no match).

The other was that your addition of `26` to the character ordinal if it was out of range needed to be moved. Without doing that, it was generating non-printable characters so the check was failing with an enchant error.